# client id for google +1 button in android app

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using google +1 button in my app. I have generated client id for it from api console. But I don't know where to place that id in code ? Anybody can suggest me. we use map id in manifest.xml but for google +1 button where can I put id ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to add the client ID to your Android app.  The client ID on other platforms is used to identify your application to Google's API endpoints.  For Android apps, your app is identified by the package name and the SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate you used to sign your app.  So the +1 button will work without adding the client ID to your app.

Instructions on how to configure the Google API console with your Android package ID and SHA1 fingerprint can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api

If you want to make authenticated calls to Google APIs as well as using +1 buttons, make sure you click **Create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID** or **Create another client ID...** to create a key which allows access to APIs.

Do NOT click *Create new Android key...* under *Simple API Access* - which is used only to identify your application to Google, and cannot be used to make authenticated API calls.

Comment: thanks for your reply...I have implemented it successfully but I had one doubt that you cleared...One more thing, can I create multipe IDs for different app in a single project in api console or I need to create different project for each app. once again thanx a lot.

Comment: You can have multiple apps with client IDs in the same project, but it is important that they are related because they will share quota, share user consent and be related in terms of deep link targeting.  If you have unrelated apps then they should each have separate projects.